# Create a csv file with two columns | Counter mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, counter

I worked on a code that is counting the occurrencies of words in a given text document and now I would like to save the output on a csv file with two columns: one for the words and one for their frequencies.

This is the code that I am trying to replicate:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(['spam', 'egg', 'spam', 'egg', 'python', 'egg'])

with open('wordfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    writer.writerow(('word', 'count'))
    writer.writerows(counter.most_common())
```

However, this is the output:

```
word countegg 3spam 2python 1
```

The output that I am trying to get should contain just two columns (one for the "word" adn one for the "frequency" and each row should contain a word and its occurrance in the text:

```
word, frequency,
the, 3165,
in, 1265,
of,1233,
```

When I print the output with the code:

```
print(open('wordfile.csv', 'rb').read())
```

I get:

```
b'word count\r\r\negg 3\r\r\nspam 2\r\r\npython 1\r\r\n')
```

As you can see there aren't the two columns for the word and the frequency.
I am using Windows and this is the Python version that I am using: 
3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)

Comment: For writing CSV, it is often easier to simply write the values using [file.write()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writer.writerow` is expecting the list of columns for the row; in you snippet your are passing all the results ie. all the columns of all the items.

You need to iter over `counter.items()` to get the result you want:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(['spam', 'egg', 'spam', 'egg', 'python', 'egg'])

with open('wordfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    writer.writerow(('word', 'count'))
    writer.writerows(counter.most_common())
```

Comment: Thanks indeed you can also use `writerows`.

Comment: by using counter.items() I get an error: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: @M.Huntz i fixed the code to use `.most_common()` and `writer.writerows` with an `s` that's what you were missing.

Comment: @M.Huntz: to get comma as a separator, drop `delimiter=' '` parameter (comma is the default).

Comment: This is the output by using the code word,count,egg,3spam,2python,1

Comment: I am trying to have just two columns (words and frequency) and each row contains a word and its frequency in the text

Comment: @M.Huntz copy-paste the code as is. It prints [two columns](http://ideone.com/nx0NHp). In general, pass `newline=''` (to preserve embedded newlines)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The code doesn't give the output expected. Is it because I am using Anaconda?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for the advice. I edited the questions by including the code suggested and the output I get. Also, when I simply paste and copy the code (with the same list of words) as in your answer I obtain the same output (no columns)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian When I use your code with sys.stdout I obtain the output expected but not when I use writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')